# Can't get denoiser settings right

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, filmic-blender

I just can't get the new denoiser feature to work for me. It producers weird "halo" type of smears even when I put the feature strength to something like 0.05, am I doing something wrong? Because everyone is praising it to work but I just can't get it optimized for my needs.

[image]

[image]

Blend File: [image]

**UPDATE, with those settings below, I was able to get this:**

[image]

[image]

**Not sure if I should be happy, will try to tweak even more**

Comment: We need more info about your setup. How many samples are you using?

Comment: 500 samples, rendering with GPU, tiles 216 by 216, 25 tiles. Image res 1080x by 1080x

Comment: Are those balls out of focus on purpose ?

Comment: yes they are, Apature is set to radius, and distance in 87cm

Comment: Using a low feature strength will give you more noise. Can you upload the blend file because I can't recreate the error.

Comment: sure I will do that right now, thanks Josip!

Comment: You can reduce the number of samples and increase the Denoising radius.
Because of the strong DoF the radius blurs only pieces of the blured image at a time. Increasing the radius will help blend the whole thing better and stop producing the halo effect.